Trying to find an animated movie or series about Marco Polo and some hotels
(Repost from Reddit)
I have a faint memory of really liking a cartoon whose plot revolved around a group of friends exploring an underwater hotel built by Marco Polo that was in someway connected to a second hotel built on some mountains (maybe the Himalayas) where the villain, I think it was a female crow, used to live.
That's pretty much all I remember and I may be mixing some things up.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you see this?

IMDB lists a "Marco Polo Junior" Australian animated movie dated 1972, and its 2001 re-edit/remake "Marco Polo: Return to Xanadu" (both pages contain scant details, but there are a few images). Have you ruled these out?

Thanks to @Ifurini I found the movie!
It was not the movies they suggested but while looking those up I ended up on the IMDB page for Cuccioli: Il codice di Marco Polo which is indeed the movie I remembered. Apparently it's part of the franchise Pet Pals so I guess I'll have to watch the whole thing now lol

The Pet Pals are put to the test when the Evil Crow Witch is determined to drain the canals of Venice. Armed with a touch of magic, the Pet Pals combine their strengths to uncover the secret code before the Evil Witch does.

Summary




Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

For a self-answer, you have to wait 48 hours...site rule.
